# $\langle Ax,x \rangle > 0$ but not symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is not symmetric, but $\langle Ax,x \rangle > 0$ for any $x\neq 0$. Is A necessarily invertible?

My Solution: $A+A^T$ must be symmetric,  $\langle A+A^Tx,x \rangle=2\langle Ax,x \rangle > 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $A+A^T$ is positive definite and thus invertible. Can this lead to $A$ necessarily invertible? How to prove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a better approach. If you're working on a finite dimensional vector space, it suffices to show that the kernel of $A$ is trivial. With respect to your inner product condition, what happens if $Ax=0$?